# Installing a unix application?

Tags: software-installation, path

I am trying to install depot_tools here are the [instructions](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/install-depot-tools).

I downloaded the file from this:

```
svn co http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/tools/depot_tools
```

I wanted to install it in `/usr/local` so I moved the download there via gui.

The next part is:

```
export PATH="$PATH":`pwd`/depot_tools
```

So I went into `.bash_login` and changed this:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

to this:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH:/usr/local/depot_tools"
```

Terminal wont recognize any of the commands `gclient, gcl, git-cl, repo`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you source the `~/.bash_login` after modifying it?  Editing a file does not automatically load it into the current shell.  Try running:

```
source ~/.bash_login
```

Just starting a new terminal emulator may not source `~/.bash_profile`; it depends on how the terminal program is invoked.